# How to make a button click cumulative?

Tags: android, kotlin, yandex-mapkit

I have a listener for my map zoom buttons:

```
class ZoomMapListener(
    mapView: MapView,
    private val zoom: Zoom
) : View.OnClickListener {

    private val localMapView = WeakReference(mapView)
    //private var clickCounter = 0

    override fun onClick(view: View?) {
        //clickCounter++
        localMapView.get()?.let {
            var cameraPosition = it.map.cameraPosition

            val zoom = if (zoom == IN) {
                cameraPosition.zoom + 1.0f
                //cameraPosition.zoom + (clickCounter * 1.0f)
            } else {
                cameraPosition.zoom - 1.0f
                //cameraPosition.zoom - (clickCounter * 1.0f)
            }

            cameraPosition = CameraPosition(
                cameraPosition.target,
                zoom,
                cameraPosition.azimuth,
                cameraPosition.tilt
            )

            it.map.move(cameraPosition, Animation(Animation.Type.SMOOTH, 0.5f), null)
        }
    }
}
```

I'm setting it like this:

```
zoomInMapButton.setOnClickListener(ZoomMapListener(mapView, Zoom.IN))
zoomOutMapButton.setOnClickListener(ZoomMapListener(mapView, Zoom.OUT))
```

But the problem is that if user is clicking on one of this buttons multiple times map is not zooming properly, because of the animation: user clicked the button -> camera position is moving for 0.5s -> in less than 0.5s user is clicking the second/third/etc. time and onClick method is taking the intermediate camera position. Because of that the behavior of zooming varies in different cases.

Because I don't want to set animation duration to zero, I've been thinking that I can make a variable to save up this click counting(it is commented in the code above), but it is not the right way, so I'm stuck

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your approach is right. Just make a few changes

```
class ZoomMapListener(
    mapView: MapView,
    private val zoom: Zoom
) : View.OnClickListener {

    private val localMapView = WeakReference(mapView)
    private var clickCounter = 0

    override fun onClick(view: View?) {
        clickCounter++
        if(clickCounter>1) return
        setZoom()
    }

    setZoom() {
        localMapView.get()?.let {
            var cameraPosition = it.map.cameraPosition

            val zoom = if (zoom == IN) {
                cameraPosition.zoom + 1.0f
                //cameraPosition.zoom + (clickCounter * 1.0f)
            } else {
                cameraPosition.zoom - 1.0f
                //cameraPosition.zoom - (clickCounter * 1.0f)
            }

            cameraPosition = CameraPosition(
                cameraPosition.target,
                zoom,
                cameraPosition.azimuth,
                cameraPosition.tilt
            )

            it.map.move(cameraPosition, Animation(Animation.Type.SMOOTH, 0.5f), null)
            clickCounter--;
            Handler().postDelayed({
                if(counter>0) setZoom()
            }, 550)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

do you have any option in map framework for stopping current animation (e.g. move)?

if you have then just call it at the begining of click method

if not then imho this is a proper solution to introduce some variable `lastClicked = System.currentTimeMillis()` and checking `if (System.currentTimeMillis() - lastClicked < 500) return` at the begining of `onClick`

Comment: i suppose this solution is gonna kinda ignore multiple taps like if i click three times it will zoom only one time, but i need it to zoom three times consistently :(

Comment: well, as an alternative you may accumulate number of clicks while last < 500 and after end of anim fire them again (call same code/methods which are called in `onClick`). note that this may cause bad UX when user click .e.g 10 times and must wait for 5 secs for finishing zooming

Comment: maybe you can save created `Animation` object for `move` method and cancel it?